# Test Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-shell

Im asked to test a Google Cloud Function triggered by http through cloud shell using the **"curl -m 60 -X GET [url_of_your_function]"** commnand.

Does anyone know where to find the url of my function? Ive tried the main url of it and many other ideas but get not solution. I cannot find any documentation on Google Cloud as documentation for GCF its very scarse and disorganized.

Answer (score 2):

See [Function URL](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) on the documentation for [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions).

The way to parse the `describe` result depends on whether you're using 1st or 2nd gen.

Once you have the URL, assuming it requires auth, you can:

```bash
ENDPOINT="$(gcloud functions describe ... )"
TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"

curl \
--get \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
${ENDPOINT}
```

`gcloud` includes a command to invoke Cloud Functions directly too:

```bash
gcloud functions call ...
```

Comment: It's worth to mention that `gcloud functions call` it's ok when doing sporadical tests since it relies on the `Test function per minute` quota. For doing lots of requests the recommendation is to make the requests directly to the HTTP endpoint of the function. https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#rate_limits

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, thanks for your answer. When trying to call the function, the following error shows: ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) ResponseError: status=[404], code=[Ok], message=[Function function-1 in region us-central1 in project fabled-badge-367810 does not exist]

Comment: At least one of the parameters is incorrect. `404` means not found. Check the name (`function-1`), the region (`us-central1`) and the project (`fabled-badge-367810`).